# How do I use re.sub to remove a repeated block of text within square brackets?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a response from an API that is a pseudo dictionary with some `'key':'values'` but mostly just a blob of text with `'key:values'`. I convert it with `.json()` to this:

`{'status': 'done', 'nextLogId': 'AQAAAXb', 'logs': [{'content': {'service': 't2pipeline', 'tags': ['tag1:value1', 'tag2:value2', 'tag3:value3'], 'timestamp': '2021-01-05T05:25:03.416Z', 'host': 'i-00e17', 'attributes': {'caller': 'psignal/state_machine.go:451', 'ts': 1609824303.416246, 'level': 'warn'}, 'message': 'psignal: Ignoring scte35 segmentation_descriptor (type:Program Start eventID:0 refUTC:Jan  5 05:25:02.387626333): there is an active segment with the same event_id'}, 'id': 'AQAAAXb'}, {'content': {'service': 't2pipeline', 'tags': ['tag1:value1', 'tag2:value2', 'tag3:value3'], 'timestamp': '2021-01-05T05:25:03.416Z', 'host': 'i-00e17', 'attributes': {'caller': 'psignal/state_machine.go:713', 't2': {'scte35': {'event_id': 0, 'event_ptr': '0xc009f32b40', 'seg_type_id': 16}}, 'ts': 1609824303.4161847, 'level': 'info'}, 'message': 'psignal: scte35 segdesc eventID:0 type:Program Start'}, 'id': 'AQAAAXb'}], 'requestId': 'OVZRd3hv'}`

There are two entries in here and in reality there will be more.

I convert to a string with `json.dumps()`

And then use `re.sub()` to remove the `'tags': []`, section from the response and return the string like so

```py
res = re.sub(r'"tags": \[.*"\],\s', "", response_string)
```

The problem is it only return the last entry.

```py
print(res)
```

`{"status": "done", "nextLogId": "AQAAAXb", "logs": [{"content": {"service": "t2pipeline", "timestamp": "2021-01-05T05:25:03.416Z", "host": "i-00e17b8e872ec7d05", "attributes": {"caller": "psignal/state_machine.go:713", "t2": {"scte35": {"event_id": 0, "event_ptr": "0xc009f32b40", "seg_type_id": 16}}, "ts": 1609824303.4161847, "level": "info"}, "message": "psignal: scte35 segdesc eventID:0 type:Program Start"}, "id": "AQAAAXb"}], "requestId": "OVZRd3hv"}`

How do I modify the regex so that every instance of `'tags': []`, is removed and returns the whole string with all entries?

Note: Since I can't `del` by key I think the only way to remove content is treating the response like a string and remove tag with regex.

Comment: Why not parse the Json and remove what you want to remove?

Comment: No you don’t really want to do this by parsing JSON text. Regex isn’t good for e.g. nested [ [ ] ]

Comment: You shouldn't work with json using regex, work with object. `del res['logs'][0]['content']['tags']` will work, just use it in loop.

Comment: Or try adapting this recursive json response explorer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540712/reading-a-json-response-recursively-with-python

Comment: @OlvinRoght I just tried to do 
for i in range(len(res)):
    for k,v in res.items():
        del res['logs'][i]['content']['tags']

print(res)

but get  - KeyError: 'tags'

Comment: Use `for i in range(len(res[‘logs’])):`

Comment: @barny This worked 
```for i in range(len(res['logs'])):
    del res['logs'][i]['content']['tags']```

Comment: Folks, thanks for the help. I initially tried processing the response like a dictionary but had been unable to access the 'tags' key. And that is why I tried string processing with regex. Thanks for steering me back to doing this with loop in a dictionary. I think that this question has merit so, if possible, please vote it up - not sure why I got a down vote based on all the information I included in the question.

Answer (score 1):

No need using regex. Use

```py
import json
res = {'status': 'done', 'nextLogId': 'AQAAAXb', 'logs': [{'content': {'service': 't2pipeline', 'tags': ['tag1:value1', 'tag2:value2', 'tag3:value3'], 'timestamp': '2021-01-05T05:25:03.416Z', 'host': 'i-00e17', 'attributes': {'caller': 'psignal/state_machine.go:451', 'ts': 1609824303.416246, 'level': 'warn'}, 'message': 'psignal: Ignoring scte35 segmentation_descriptor (type:Program Start eventID:0 refUTC:Jan  5 05:25:02.387626333): there is an active segment with the same event_id'}, 'id': 'AQAAAXb'}, {'content': {'service': 't2pipeline', 'tags': ['tag1:value1', 'tag2:value2', 'tag3:value3'], 'timestamp': '2021-01-05T05:25:03.416Z', 'host': 'i-00e17', 'attributes': {'caller': 'psignal/state_machine.go:713', 't2': {'scte35': {'event_id': 0, 'event_ptr': '0xc009f32b40', 'seg_type_id': 16}}, 'ts': 1609824303.4161847, 'level': 'info'}, 'message': 'psignal: scte35 segdesc eventID:0 type:Program Start'}, 'id': 'AQAAAXb'}], 'requestId': 'OVZRd3hv'}
for i in range(len(res['logs'])):
    del res['logs'][i]['content']['tags']
print(res)
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##3VNNj9MwEL33V8wtrcQWx07SriUOFVyKkPhaENqqqtxkmhgldrDd7q5W/e3FjstSxPIHiHLIvMyM38x77h9coxU7nWTXa@Pgu9VqZNDCK3hMrBNubxMOSaUVJi8gUXjv3ul6WQVw8XGxWHzbBrzVdchbPSalVg6V84GvR3OQJYZcR3vZYytjGydievhI@UG0e0zPOI0hPYcshixZh1h26Dl1fehICU2viH/zG5JzmnPCplla3IbCRtvAIJFXhGA6C5Bwzsjt3qEdqJWibdGEnN7KWon2ZRgWN50oG09yWmue5ZFTKEgLcj2nGYtn0KwIM@MB29DhThiVHD3i2VlR40VXDstaaSNVDbZ0yHKwWHd@P8JJrTYV2tLI3mkDY/fQI/9gdG1EB5@d8GL4A5RbvuEEDO6@3Lzmb4UCyOE8L52y@aygBWNswsE1aBCkBZ8jSicP@OssuJOuCf/Big5j142sBsryDyU98j8pOEvZQILGWQYBhs@nFXAgPiGGvRu6kfuSkOsdo9uMhGq/xE3QJqanxfH4vCnSeTa7dIVUO/1PV/w2Q7DAhdB/u@A5mcIqDf7Y@13Gq/j@6@2nijWH5DjaeTNJkAqMUDWOW1Rjf59X8YquJxM@Av9U2MIFvJLr1ZPw61WUdz3qvXNdKJ@MTqef)

**Results**:

```
{'status': 'done', 'nextLogId': 'AQAAAXb', 'logs': [{'content': {'service': 't2pipeline', 'timestamp': '2021-01-05T05:25:03.416Z', 'host': 'i-00e17', 'attributes': {'caller': 'psignal/state_machine.go:451', 'ts': 1609824303.416246, 'level': 'warn'}, 'message': 'psignal: Ignoring scte35 segmentation_descriptor (type:Program Start eventID:0 refUTC:Jan  5 05:25:02.387626333): there is an active segment with the same event_id'}, 'id': 'AQAAAXb'}, {'content': {'service': 't2pipeline', 'timestamp': '2021-01-05T05:25:03.416Z', 'host': 'i-00e17', 'attributes': {'caller': 'psignal/state_machine.go:713', 't2': {'scte35': {'event_id': 0, 'event_ptr': '0xc009f32b40', 'seg_type_id': 16}}, 'ts': 1609824303.4161847, 'level': 'info'}, 'message': 'psignal: scte35 segdesc eventID:0 type:Program Start'}, 'id': 'AQAAAXb'}], 'requestId': 'OVZRd3hv'}
```